# Replacing line breaks within quotes

Tags: javascript, python, regex, csv, replace

I have a TSV file that contain multiple columns, but it doesn't seem to be aligned properly. There are linebreaks between quotes in one column (the column "Examples" in the example). I want to put all the example sentences (within quotes) under the same column. How can I fix that using Python (and Javascript)?

```
example.tsv - actual output

ID   Data   Fruit   Examples
1   August   Apple   "I have an apple. (Ana) 
I give her an apple. (Tomas) 
There are apples (Lisa)"
2   July   Melon   "I have a melon. (Ana) 
I give him a melon. (Tomas) 
There are melons (Lisa)"
3   May   Lemon   "I have a lemon. (Ana) 
I give him a lemon. (Tomas) 
There are lemons (Lisa)"
...
```

```
example.tsv - ideal output

ID   Data   Fruit   Examples
1   August   Apple   "I have an apple. (Ana) I give her an apple. (Tomas) There are apples (Lisa)"
2   July   Melon   "I have a melon. (Ana) I give him a melon. (Tomas) There are melons (Lisa)"
3   May   Lemon   "I have a lemon. (Ana) I give him a lemon. (Tomas) There are lemons (Lisa)"
```

EDITED:
Thank you all for advice and sorry for the confusion. I indeed need Python codes at the moment, but I was going to do it with Javascript too.  This is what I've gotten so far on Python, using regex, but this doesn't merge the sentences together....

```
df = 'example.tsv'
import re
with open(df, 'r+', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    content = file.read()
    content_replaced = re.sub('[^\S\r\n]*[\n\r]\s*', " ", content)
    print(content)
```

Comment: To be clear, it's aligned perfectly correctly by CSV standards. The field is quoted, so it (and therefore the record it's part of) doesn't end until the close quote (the record itself ending at the next newline that is not part of a quoted field). *Humans* see the separate lines, as do non-CSV text readers, but from the CSV/TSV parser's point of view, each of those three line groups constitutes a *single* record with four fields.

Comment: They are in the same column by TSV rules. The newlines in the quotes are escaped so do not start new rows. When read, you should get cells with newlines in them. Note: the data you posted is not tab delimited. But if you fix that and use a reader with delimiter="\t" (at least in python), it should work.

Comment: Please narrow the question to JavaScript *or* Python. Asking for both just makes it harder to rank answers. Which language do you actually need the solution in?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression - replace all new lines after a quote and following non-quote characters and before non-quote characters and a quote:

```js
const src = `ID   Data   Fruit   Examples
1   August   Apple   "I have an apple. (Ana) 
I give her an apple. (Tomas) 
There are apples (Lisa)"
2   July   Melon   "I have a melon. (Ana) 
I give him a melon. (Tomas) 
There are melons (Lisa)"
3   May   Lemon   "I have a lemon. (Ana) 
I give him a lemon. (Tomas) 
There are lemons (Lisa)"`

$pre.textContent = src.replace(/(?<="[^"]+)\n(?=[^"]+")/g, '');
```

```html
<pre id="$pre"></pre>
```

Comment: Parsing CSV (and dialects thereof, like TSV) with a regex is a fraught (read: ugly and error-prone) process. Why not just parse it with the `csv` module to actually split the fields up properly, perform any replacements on the specific field(s) in question, then use the `csv` module to serialize it properly, rather than risk an edge case in an unmaintainable regex that breaks it down the line? Admittedly, the OP's sample is not CSV or TSV, so if it's not *really* a CSV-related dialect, that won't work, but if it's not, that just adds more edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

That's already a valid TSV file - since the newlines are in quotes, the newline becomes part of the single cell, it doesn't start a new row. Nothing says a computer format like TSV has to be pretty to look at. But if you did want to consolodate, and you were using python, you could read with a CSV parser, change the cell and write:

```
import csv

with open("test.tsv", newline="") as infile, open("testout.tsv", "w", newline="") as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter="\t")
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter="\t")
    for row in reader:
        row[3] = " ".join(row[3].split())
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Note that you've lost information - the newlines were delimiting the sentences.

Answer (score 0):

This is difficult to answer, you need to include some code and tell us what you already tried.

That said, here's an example of how you could do this with Javascript, assuming you already have that column's text as a variable.

```
// 'text' defined like in your example above. 
// With quote marks at the start and end and with line breaks as \n
const text = '"I have an apple. (Ana)\nI give her an apple. (Tomas)\nThere are apples(Lisa)"';

// To replace the linebreaks with a space character using regular expression:
const regexText = text.replace( /\n/g, " ");

// To replace the linebreaks with a space character using split/join
const splitJoinText = text.split("\n").join(" ");
```